# Launch a stored procedure when a datetime is expired

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

Can I launch in SQL Server a stored procedure when a datetime value (stored in a table) is expired?

I have a stored procedure that will send a message with [MSMQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472.aspx), and I need to do this as soon as the datetime is expired.

I am using SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a [SQL Agent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189237.aspx) job. This can poll your column and fire your stored procedure when the datetime exceeds a specified value.

Alternatively, if your stored procedure needs to run at exactly the specified time, schedule a SQL Agent job to fire at that exact time and don't poll. You can do this programmatically via the [sp_add_jobschedule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366342.aspx) system stored procedure, or manually depending on your requirements.

Using the latter method you could remove the logic that writes the desired time to a table. If that table value is still required however, you could create a trigger on that table that invokes sp_add_jobschedule to create a job schedule.

Comment: I already have created SQL Agent job. The problem is that I have to scheduled the job every x minute. I need to fire the stored procedure as soon as possible the datatime exceeds the expiration date.

Comment: Understood @overcomer, I have edited my answer to reflect your requirements. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option:

It would require a little more 'setup', but have a look at Service Broker [timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187804.aspx) and [activation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171617.aspx).  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079363/can-i-get-sql-server-to-call-a-stored-proc-every-n-seconds) is an example of how you might utilize this functionality.  Service Broker even works on Sql Express (which doesn't have the Sql Agent).